# How do I override Django's default form error templates - at the project level?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I know this topic has been asked a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097407/how-to-override-default-django-forgot-password-template) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522697/django-does-not-override-template) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582087/how-do-i-override-djangos-default-admin-templates-and-layouts) on StackOverflow, and [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/overriding-templates/) seem pretty clear about how to do it, but it's not working for me and I'm stumped.

Overriding at the project level makes the most sense to me so I created a templates directory outside my app directories - at the same level as `manage.py` - and I added that directory path to my `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` setting

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'], # Allow overriding of other apps templates
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I'd like to override the error templates for all forms at once, but I'm testing it with just a single ModelForm at the moment.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Inside the View I create an instance of the form, instantiating it with some request data and the values from the model object matching the id passed in the request.

```
mymodelinstance = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=kwargs['mymodel_id'])
form = MyForm(request_data, instance=mymodelinstance)
```

I checked where the form is getting its error template by printing the path in the View

```
print(form.errors.template_name)
```

The print statement printed `django/forms/errors/dict/default.html` so I put a new custom `default.html` file inside `mydjangoproject/templates/django/forms/errors/dict/`.

This doesn't work however. My new `default.html` template file isn't being used. Any ideas for what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Found solution for this?

Comment: @RohitReddyAbbadi Unfortunately not